# My viewmodel doesnt increment numbers depending on JSON result knockout

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have the following JSON object:

```
Object {domainCount: 1, preOrderCode: "something"}
```

I call it like this in my viewModel:

```
this.preOrderedDomains = ko.observableArray([]);
this.hasPreOrder = function(domainSearchResult, event) {
            var data = {
                'preOrderCode' : this.preOrderCode,
                'domainCount' : this.domainCount,
                }

            $.ajax('/ajax-check-preorder.do', { 
            data: data,
            type: "post", 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                if (utils.getProperty('domainCount',result, true) ) {
                    self.preOrderedDomains.push(domainSearchResult);
                 }
                        console.log(result);

                }
            });
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.preOrderedDomains(), function (domainCount) {
        return domainCount == domainSearchResult.domainCount;
    }).length;

    }
```

It checks if there is a preorder when you refresh the page. 
If there is, it should display the following in the DOM:

```
<div class="preOrdered" data-bind="visible: $root.domainSearch.hasPreOrder($data)">
            <strong class="single_domain" data-bind="visible: $root.domainSearch.preOrderedDomains().length <= 1">
            <span class="update--domain" data-bind="text: domainSearch.preOrderedDomains().length"></span>&nbsp;<bean:message key="site.domain.search.selected.domain" />
            </strong>
            <strong class="multiple_domains" data-bind="visible: $root.domainSearch.preOrderedDomains().length >= 2">
            <span class="update--domain" data-bind="text: domainSearch.preOrderedDomains().length"></span>&nbsp;<bean:message key="site.domain.search.selected.domains" />
            </strong>
        </div>
```

When I reload it shows fine the number one if there is a domainCount of one. But it doesnt increment the number. 
So if there is 2 or 3 etc ends up in an infinte loop.

Does anyone have an idea of what Im doing wrong?

Comment: One possibility can be that your DOM is getting bound before the ajax request returns the promise and domainSearch.preOrderedDomains().length is updated. Also, can you please tell more about the significance of "domainSearch" cuz I couldnt find it in the viewmodel

Comment: The domainSearch is used to initiate the viewModel that the above is a part of. So it returns the searched results that ends up in the sessions that the check-for-preorder is using.

Comment: But after changing it to the above, it starts an infinite loop that just keeps incrementing the counter :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind your `.preOrdered` `div` visibility to a function. Don't do that. Instead, bind to an observable or computed observable.

A second thing to ask yourself this: are you okay with the page initially showing with the `div` hidden, and it popping up once the Ajax request is done? Or do you want to show anything until it's done?

In the latter case, you perhaps shouldn't call `ko.applyBindings` until in the `success` handler.

In either case, I recommend this for a `hasPreorder` observable and setting its value:

```
var self = this;

self.preOrderedDomains = ko.observableArray([]);
self.hasPreOrder = ko.observable(false);

self.updateHasPreorder = function(domainSearchResult, event) {
    var data = {
        'preOrderCode' : self.preOrderCode,
        'domainCount' : self.domainCount,
    };

    $.ajax('/ajax-check-preorder.do', { 
        data: data,
        type: "post", 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            if (utils.getProperty('domainCount',result, true) ) {
                self.preOrderedDomains.push(domainSearchResult);
            }
            console.log(result);

            var hasPreorderNew = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.preOrderedDomains(), function (domainCount) {
                return domainCount === domainSearchResult.domainCount;
            }).length

            self.hasPreorder(hasPreorderNew);
        }
    });
}
```

Then call `self.updateHasPreorder` at an appropriate time in your app, e.g. when it first loads, or upon fired subscription of other observables.